# PySpark filter a list of element and then merge back

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

My `rdd` contains pair of `IDs` and a `list` of items. for example, each item will be like `(1, [a, b, c])`. I need to apply a `filter` to this item. Let say I don't want an on the `list`.

My current approach is to use `flatMapValues` to break the items into key-value pairs. `filter` them and use `groupByKey` to merge them back into `(1, [b, c])`.

After I did some research and seems like `groupByKey` is terrible when data is huge. Also, seems like I'm breaking down the `list`, and them merging it back after the `list` might seems redundant. Is there a way to accomplish this without break the `array` down and `merge` it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `mapValues`:

```
rdd2 = rdd1.mapValues(lambda l: [i for i in l if i != 'a'])
```